# JPA queries SELECT is not working

Tags: java, jpa, import

I  have the following problem, I would like my application to list all the `Weapons` from the database. This is method `getDbWeapons`:

```
 public ArrayList<Weapon> getDbWeapons()
    {
        ArrayList<Weapon> dbWeapons = new ArrayList<>();
        EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
            entr.begin();
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Weapon i", Weapon.class);
        query.setParameter("itemid", dbWeapons);
        dbWeapons = (ArrayList<Weapon>) query.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        /*
        Stáhne všechny zbraně ze serveru a vrátí je jako ArrayList.
        Nezapomeň při vkládání doplnit parametr Item.type!
        */
        return dbWeapons;
    }
```

This is my class `Armor`:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dke.ps.Tables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author michal
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "armor")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByItemid", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.itemid = :itemid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByName", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByValue", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.value = :value")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByDescription", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.description = :description")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByIcon", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.icon = :icon")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByType", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.type = :type")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByDefence", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.defence = :defence")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Armor.findByPrice", query = "SELECT a FROM Armor a WHERE a.price = :price")})
public class Armor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemid")
    private Integer itemid;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "value")
    private Integer value;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "icon")
    private String icon;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type;
    @Column(name = "defence")
    private Integer defence;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemid", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private ItemsId itemsId;

    public Armor() {
    }

    public Armor(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public Integer getItemid() {
        return itemid;
    }

    public void setItemid(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getDefence() {
        return defence;
    }

    public void setDefence(Integer defence) {
        this.defence = defence;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public ItemsId getItemsId() {
        return itemsId;
    }

    public void setItemsId(ItemsId itemsId) {
        this.itemsId = itemsId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (itemid != null ? itemid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Armor)) {
            return false;
        }
        Armor other = (Armor) object;
        if ((this.itemid == null && other.itemid != null) || (this.itemid != null && !this.itemid.equals(other.itemid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.dke.ps.Tables.Armor[ itemid=" + itemid + " ]";
    }

}
```

And this is my class `Shop`, which should show the items:

```
package com.dke.ps.Shop;

import static com.dke.ps.Constants.Constants.*;
import com.dke.ps.CustomTypes.ImagePanel;
import com.dke.ps.Items.Armor;
import com.dke.ps.Items.Item;
import com.dke.ps.Items.Potion;
import com.dke.ps.Items.Weapon;
import com.dke.ps.Server.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/**
 * Class implementing in-app-purchaces (microtransactions).
 * @author vitvalecka
 */
public class Shop extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener
{
    private Server server;
    private User user;

    private JPanel panelShop;
    private JPanel panelItemDetail;
    private JPanel panelItemList;
    private JScrollPane spItemListScroll;

    private JList listItems;
    private DefaultListModel dlmItems = new DefaultListModel();
    private JButton btnBuy = new JButton("Buy");
    private JLabel lItemName = new JLabel();
    private ImagePanel ipItemImage;
    private JLabel lPrice = new JLabel();
    private JLabel lEffect = new JLabel();
    private JLabel lBought = new JLabel();
    private JButton btnReloadShop = new JButton("Reload Shop");

    private JPanel panelShopAdminButtons;
    private JButton btnAddItem = new JButton("Add");
    private JButton btnEditItem = new JButton("Edit");
    private JButton btnDeleteItem = new JButton("Delete");

    private ArrayList<Item> listOfDbItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> listOfUsersItems = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Shop window initialization.
     * @param server    database server to connect
     * @param user      user entering the store
     */
    public Shop(Server server, User user)
    {
        super();
        this.server = server;
        this.user = user;

        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Shop");
        setSize(SHOP_SIZE_X, SHOP_SIZE_Y);

        panelShop = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(panelShop);
        panelShop.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow, fill]"));

        panelItemDetail = new JPanel();
        panelItemDetail.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                "wrap",
                "[grow, fill]"
        ));

        panelItemDetail.add(lItemName);
        panelItemDetail.add(lPrice);
        panelItemDetail.add(lEffect);
        panelItemDetail.add(lBought);
        panelItemDetail.add(btnBuy);
        btnBuy.addActionListener((e)->{
            buy();
        });

        if ((user.getUsername() == SHOP_ADMIN_USERNAME) && (user.isLoginOk()))
        {
            panelShopAdminButtons = new JPanel();
            panelShopAdminButtons.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow, fill]"));
            panelShopAdminButtons.add(btnAddItem);
            panelShopAdminButtons.add(btnEditItem);
            panelShopAdminButtons.add(btnDeleteItem);

            btnAddItem.addActionListener((e)->{
                new AddEditItem(server, null);
            });

            btnEditItem.addActionListener((e)->{
                if (getSelectedItem() != null)
                {
                    new AddEditItem(server, getSelectedItem());
                }
            });

            btnDeleteItem.addActionListener((e)->{
                if (getSelectedItem() != null)
                {
                    server.removeItemFromDb(getSelectedItem().id);
                }
            });
        }

        panelItemList = new JPanel();
        panelItemList.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                "wrap",
                "[grow, fill]"
        ));

        loadItems();
        listItems = new JList(dlmItems);
        spItemListScroll = new JScrollPane(listItems);
        panelItemList.add(spItemListScroll);
        listItems.addListSelectionListener(this);
        listItems.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        listItems.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        listItems.setVisibleRowCount(VISIBLE_ITEMS);
        panelItemList.add(btnReloadShop);
        btnReloadShop.addActionListener((e)->{
            loadItems();
        });

        panelShop.add(panelItemList);

        ipItemImage = new ImagePanel("");
        String formatingString = "height " + ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE + ":" + ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE + ":" + ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE;
        panelItemList.add(ipItemImage, formatingString);

        panelItemList.add(panelItemDetail);

        btnReloadShop.addActionListener((e)->{loadItems();});

        setFocusableWindowState(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusableWindowState(true);
    }

    private void loadItems()
    {
        listOfDbItems = server.getDbItems();
        listOfUsersItems = server.getPurchasedItems(user);
        dlmItems.clear();

        int numberOfItemsInDb = listOfDbItems.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInDb; i++)
        {
            dlmItems.addElement((listOfDbItems.get(i)).name);
        }
    }

    private void buy()
    {
        int selectedIndex = listItems.getSelectedIndex();
        int selectedItemId = (listOfDbItems.get(selectedIndex)).id;
        server.purchaseItem(user, selectedItemId);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false)
        {
            int selectedIndex = listItems.getSelectedIndex();

            if (selectedIndex >= 0)
            {

                Item selectedItem = listOfDbItems.get(selectedIndex);

                lItemName.setText(selectedItem.name);
                ipItemImage = new ImagePanel(selectedItem.icon);  
                lPrice.setText("Price: " + selectedItem.price);

                if (instancesInInventory(selectedItem) > 0)
                {
                    lBought.setText(
                            "You have already bought " +
                            instancesInInventory(selectedItem) +
                            " pieces."
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    lBought.setText("You have not bought this item yet.");
                }

                switch (selectedItem.type) {
                    case WEAPON_ID:
                    {
                        lEffect.setText("Power: " + ((Weapon)selectedItem).power);
                        break;
                    }
                    case ARMOR_ID:
                    {
                        lEffect.setText("Defence: " + ((Armor)selectedItem).defence);
                        break;
                    }
                    case POTION_ID:
                    {
                        lEffect.setText("Heals " + ((Potion)selectedItem).healRate + " points of health");
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int instancesInInventory(Item selectedItem)
    {
        int numberOfInstances = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfUsersItems.size(); i++)
        {
            if (selectedItem.id == listOfUsersItems.get(i))
            {
                numberOfInstances++;
            }
        }

        return numberOfInstances;
    }

    private Item getSelectedItem()
    {
        int selectedIndex = listItems.getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                return listOfDbItems.get(selectedIndex);
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Could you help me with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: No records are displayed and I do not know where the problem is.

Comment: most probably in your query. debug the code where you try to get values from the database and also execute the query directly on your database to see if its working there

Comment: Yes, I also think so. But I do not know exactly where the problem is, I was looking at the some tutorials and I think it should be okay

Comment: So look in the LOG of your chosen JPA provider. It tells you the SQL invoked, which you could easily invoke manually to see what results it sees. This is called debugging. And then you DEBUG whether the problem is in the database retrieval or in your java code, because simply posting a pile of code does nothing to isolate an issue ...

Comment: try to get all results you want from the database directly. if its working use the query in your java code. if that is working you are fine. if not, search for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to get all of the `Weapon` entries, then I dont know why you are trying to set a query parameter. Also use interfaces instead of concrete implementations:

```
public List<Weapon> getDbWeapons()
{
    List<Weapon> dbWeapons = new ArrayList<>();
    EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
    TypedQuery<Weapon> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Weapon i", Weapon.class);
    dbWeapons = query.getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return dbWeapons;
}
```

and use `TypedQuery` if you can.

If you want to use a query param then you need to specify it in the statement:

```
TypedQuery<Weapon> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Weapon i where itemType = :itemType", Weapon.class);
query.setParameter("itemType", "iron");
dbWeapons = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes, it's clear to me now :) Okay, so that your code is definitely correct and therefore the problem will be somewhere else? I deleted the set line and it still do not show anything, will the problem be somewhere else than in that query?

Comment: did you map the Weapon table using jpa properly? You did not post that part so double check there